# Meteor.js not updating

Tags: javascript, meteor, updates

Just installed Meteor on Linux mint Mate qiana x32. When I try to do: `meteor update`

I get this:

```
/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: DDP disconnected
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend.apply (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/service-connection.js:107:31)
    at _.extend.call (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/service-connection.js:84:17)
    at Object.exports.callPackageServer (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:51:20)
    at loadRemotePackageData (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:81:30)
    at getSomeData (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:158:20)
    at _updateServerPackageData (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:200:7)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:109:15
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:254:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:247:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:245:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:236:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:235:19)
    at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/package-client.js:108:16)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/catalog-remote.js:717:36
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:340:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:333:34
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:331:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:307:26)
    at _.extend.refresh (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/catalog-remote.js:716:18)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:71:22
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:60:11
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:254:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:247:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:245:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:236:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/buildmessage.js:235:19)
    at exports.doOrDie (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:59:31)
    at refreshOfficialCatalogOrDie (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:70:3)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:1769:3)
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/main.js:1255:23
    - - - - -
    at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.sjrnt6++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/service-connection.js:69:26
    at packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:100
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105)
    at _.extend._cleanup (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:99)
    at _.extend._lostConnection (packages/ddp/stream_client_common.js:201)
    at packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:171
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108)
```

What is this error? How can I fix this?

Is there any linux distribution that I can use with meteor without having any problem?

SOLUTION:
Tried this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2789 like @David Weldon suggested
but no results for me still had the same problems.

The solution for me was using a faster and more reliable Internet connection, I switched to using lan cable instead of WIFI.

Now it works like a charm.

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Try to close the terminal and open a new one and then try?

Comment: It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2789).

Comment: I tried to search couldn't find that issue thank you very much for doing that for me @DavidWeldon